# Upgrade Macbook air OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, upgrade

I am trying to install Skype for business and Microsoft office on my MacBook Air 2015. but need to update to macOS 10.11 for this.

I don't have any installation updates pending, how can I upgrade?

Comment: Please don't write in all caps, it is hard to read and looks like you are shouting. Also, which specific model of the Macbook Air do you have?

Comment: Sure. Its Macbook Air 13.

Comment: Specific model. Macbook Air 13 covers many different models over 10 years.

Comment: 2015 Early. 13-inch.

Answer (score 2):

Major releases need to be downloaded from the App Store. Just go there, it probably is shown on the main page (otherwise search for "Big Sur").

It is recommended to make a backup of your system first before starting the upgrade. Apple has more details in https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201475.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. So just download big Sur from Appstore? Thats all? Thanks.